# Images inside a customadapter not updating like strings are to fill a listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I'll try my best explaining whats happening, so my code has a forloop which fills a listview, this listview is showing all the correct data from a json file, excpet for the images, the images are always from the last position in the listview and then copied to the one above, for example here [image]

This is one single activity which i just and to snippet to make it fit. I'm guessing its something to do with the strings which i create to make the images,  they are somehow being used twice, and then used again to fill the listview, even though all of the other strings are being reset and filled when its gets the new information from the JSON. Heres my code if anyone would could tell me why this is only happening to the images and not the strings which create the names of items

```
String ChampionName;
String item2;
String item3;
String item4;

private String ItemName;
private String ItemName2;
private String ItemName3;
private String ItemName4;
private String ItemName5;
private String ItemName6;

private String ItemNameHW;
private String ItemName2HW;
private String ItemName3HW;
private String ItemName4HW;
private String ItemName5HW;
private String ItemName6HW;


private ListView Champ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/
    new JSONTask().execute("http://api.champion.gg/champion/aatrox/");

      Champ = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Layoutmodel>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Layoutmodel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);
            List<Layoutmodel> LayoutModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            //Number changes to what ever role you want it to be
            //JSONObject finalObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(jsonarray.length()-1);

            for (int k = 0; k < jsonarray.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(k);

            Layoutmodel layoutmodel = new Layoutmodel();
            layoutmodel.setChampionName2(finalObject.getString("key"));
            layoutmodel.setRole(finalObject.getString("role"));

            ChampionName = finalObject.getString("key");
            String role = finalObject.getString("role");
            String overallPosition = finalObject.getString("overallPosition");

            JSONObject ItemArray4 = new JSONObject(overallPosition);
            String champpos = ItemArray4.getString("position");


            String items = finalObject.getString("items");

            JSONObject ItemArray = new JSONObject(items);


            item2 = ItemArray.getString("mostGames");
            item3 = ItemArray.getString("highestWinPercent");
            JSONObject ItemArray2 = new JSONObject(item2);
            JSONObject ItemArray3 = new JSONObject(item3);
            item3 = ItemArray2.getString("items");
            item4 = ItemArray3.getString("items");


            JSONArray jsonarray2 = new JSONArray(item3);
            JSONArray jsonarray3 = new JSONArray(item4);

            JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 6);
                ItemName = finalObject2.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject3 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 5);
            ItemName2 = finalObject3.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject4 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 4);
            ItemName3 = finalObject4.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject5 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 3);
            ItemName4 = finalObject5.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject6 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 2);
            ItemName5 = finalObject6.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject7 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(jsonarray2.length() - 1);
            ItemName6 = finalObject7.getString("name");

            //Highest win names
            JSONObject finalObject8 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 6);
            ItemNameHW = finalObject8.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject9 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 5);
            ItemName2HW = finalObject9.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject10 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 4);
            ItemName3HW = finalObject10.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject11 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 3);
            ItemName4HW = finalObject11.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject12 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 2);
            ItemName5HW = finalObject12.getString("name");

            JSONObject finalObject13 = jsonarray3.getJSONObject(jsonarray3.length() - 1);
            ItemName6HW = finalObject13.getString("name");


            layoutmodel.setItem1(ItemName);
            layoutmodel.setItem2(ItemName2);
            layoutmodel.setItem3(ItemName3);
            layoutmodel.setItem4(ItemName4);
            layoutmodel.setItem5(ItemName5);
            layoutmodel.setItem6(ItemName6);

            layoutmodel.setItem1HW(ItemNameHW);
            layoutmodel.setItem2HW(ItemName2HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem3HW(ItemName3HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem4HW(ItemName4HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem5HW(ItemName5HW);
            layoutmodel.setItem6HW(ItemName6HW);


            layoutmodel.setRole(role);
            layoutmodel.setChampionName2(ChampionName);
            layoutmodel.setChamppos(champpos);
            LayoutModelList.add(layoutmodel);


        }
            return LayoutModelList;


        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Layoutmodel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        LayoutAdapter adapter2 = new LayoutAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rows, result);
        Champ.setAdapter(adapter2);


    }

}

public class LayoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<Layoutmodel> LayoutModelList2;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public LayoutAdapter(Context context2, int resource, List<Layoutmodel> objects) {
        super(context2, resource, objects);
        LayoutModelList2 = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position2, View convertView2, ViewGroup parent2) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView2 == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView2 = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.nameofchamp = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.position = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.smalltxt);
            holder.Champposition = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView17);


            String ItemNameInLowerCase;
            String ItemName2InLowerCase;
            String ItemName3InLowerCase;
            String ItemName4InLowerCase;
            String ItemName5InLowerCase;
            String ItemName6InLowerCase;

            String ItemName2InLowerCaseHW;
            String ItemName3InLowerCaseHW;
            String ItemName4InLowerCaseHW;
            String ItemName5InLowerCaseHW;
            String ItemName6InLowerCaseHW;

            holder.Champitemimg1 = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
            holder.Champitemimg2 = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            holder.Champitemimg3 = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.Champitemimg4 = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            holder.Champitemimg5 = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            holder.Champitemimg6 = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            holder.Champitemimg1HW = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
            holder.Champitemimg2HW = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
            holder.Champitemimg3HW = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            holder.Champitemimg4HW = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
            holder.Champitemimg5HW = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
            holder.Champitemimg6HW = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView13);

            ImageView imgtesta;
            String ChampionNameinlower;
            imgtesta = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            ChampionNameinlower = ChampionName.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            int id10 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ChampionNameinlower + "_square_0", null, null);
            imgtesta.setImageResource(id10);


            holder.champitem1 = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
            holder.champitem2 = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            holder.champitem3 = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            holder.champitem4 = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            holder.champitem5 = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            holder.champitem6 = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            holder.champitem1HW = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
            holder.champitem2HW = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            holder.champitem3HW = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
            holder.champitem4HW = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
            holder.champitem5HW = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
            holder.champitem6HW = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

            holder.nameofchamp.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getChampionName2());
            holder.position.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getRole());
            holder.Champposition.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getChamppos());

            holder.champitem1.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem1());
            holder.champitem2.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem2());
            holder.champitem3.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem3());
            holder.champitem4.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem4());
            holder.champitem5.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem5());
            holder.champitem6.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem6());

            holder.champitem1HW.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem1HW());
            holder.champitem2HW.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem2HW());
            holder.champitem3HW.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem3HW());
            holder.champitem4HW.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem4HW());
            holder.champitem5HW.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem5HW());
            holder.champitem6HW.setText(LayoutModelList2.get(position2).getItem6HW());

            ItemNameInLowerCase = ItemName.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName2InLowerCase = ItemName2.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName3InLowerCase = ItemName3.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName4InLowerCase = ItemName4.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName5InLowerCase = ItemName5.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName6InLowerCase = ItemName6.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");

            String itemNameInLowerCaseHW = ItemNameHW.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName2InLowerCaseHW = ItemName2HW.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName3InLowerCaseHW = ItemName3HW.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName4InLowerCaseHW = ItemName4HW.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName5InLowerCaseHW = ItemName5HW.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName6InLowerCaseHW = ItemName6HW.toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");


            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemNameInLowerCase, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg1.setImageResource(id);

            int id2 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName2InLowerCase, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg2.setImageResource(id2);

            int id3 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName3InLowerCase, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg3.setImageResource(id3);

            int id4 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName4InLowerCase, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg4.setImageResource(id4);

            int id5 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName5InLowerCase, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg5.setImageResource(id5);

            int id6 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName6InLowerCase, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg6.setImageResource(id6);


            int idHW = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + itemNameInLowerCaseHW, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg1HW.setImageResource(idHW);

            int id2HW = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName2InLowerCaseHW, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg2HW.setImageResource(id2HW);

            int id3HW = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName3InLowerCaseHW, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg3HW.setImageResource(id3HW);

            int id4HW = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName4InLowerCaseHW, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg4HW.setImageResource(id4HW);

            int id5HW = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName5InLowerCaseHW, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg5HW.setImageResource(id5HW);

            int id6HW = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.kripzy.url:drawable/" + ItemName6InLowerCaseHW, null, null);
            holder.Champitemimg6HW.setImageResource(id6HW);
            convertView2.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView2.getTag();
        }
        return convertView2;
    }
```

Newly added holder;

```
TextView nameofchamp;
TextView position;
TextView Champposition;

TextView champitem1;
TextView champitem2;
TextView champitem3;
TextView champitem4;
TextView champitem5;
TextView champitem6;

TextView champitem1HW;
TextView champitem2HW;
TextView champitem3HW;
TextView champitem4HW;
TextView champitem5HW;
TextView champitem6HW;

ImageView Champitemimg1;
ImageView Champitemimg2;
ImageView Champitemimg3;
ImageView Champitemimg4;
ImageView Champitemimg5;
ImageView Champitemimg6;

ImageView Champitemimg1HW;
ImageView Champitemimg2HW;
ImageView Champitemimg3HW;
ImageView Champitemimg4HW;
ImageView Champitemimg5HW;
ImageView Champitemimg6HW;

    }
}
```

When i put a log.v at the bottom of the code, it always replies this

```
05-21 14:41:40.646 4536-4536/com.example.kripzy.url V/Where is my error: enchantment:bloodrazor
05-21 14:41:40.659 4536-4536/com.example.kripzy.url V/Where is my error: enchantment:bloodrazor
```

Comment: I really suggest using Retrofit. It would make this code much cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

So what i was doing wrong was i was just using a string which just contained the information from the last entry on the listview, hence why it was only showing the images from it, so to fix this i had to change it to the following;

```
            ItemNameInLowerCase = holder.champitem1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName2InLowerCase = holder.champitem2.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName3InLowerCase = holder.champitem3.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName4InLowerCase = holder.champitem4.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName5InLowerCase = holder.champitem5.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName6InLowerCase = holder.champitem6.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");

            ItemNameInLowerCaseHW = holder.champitem1HW.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName2InLowerCaseHW = holder.champitem2HW.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName3InLowerCaseHW = holder.champitem3HW.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName4InLowerCaseHW = holder.champitem4HW.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName5InLowerCaseHW = holder.champitem5HW.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemName6InLowerCaseHW = holder.champitem6HW.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
```